# How to configure Celery to send email alerts when tasks fail?

Tags: celery, flower

How is it possible to configure celery to send email alerts when tasks are failing?

For example I want Celery to notify me when more than 3 tasks fail or more than 10 tasks are being retried.

Is it possible using celery or a utility (e.g. flower) or I have to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is set [`CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True`](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-send-task-error-emails) and if Celery process fails django will send message with traceback to all emails set in `ADMINS` settings.

Comment: Yes, thanks. but it has a problem that it sends an email for every failed task.

Comment: Also is has nothing to do with Django, it will work even if you don't use Celery with Django as long as all the right config entries are there.

Comment: The question was about getting alerts when a threshold of failed or retried tasks is reached, not sending an email for every task (could be thousands).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626946/how-to-get-the-failed-tasks-in-celery/32859547#32859547) to get list of failed tasks, from which you could calculate stats to send an alert.

Comment: Is this option available for celery 4.x? I couldn't find such.

Comment: Not available anymore in version 4.x

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible out of the box.

You could write custom client on top of celery or flower or directly accessing RabbitMQ.

What I would do (and I am doing) is simply logging failed tasks and then use something like [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/) to monitor the log files, this works for all your infrastructure, not just Celery.

You can also use something like [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) which monitors your processes directly and offers many other features. Although email reporting on exceptions is somewhat limited in NewRelic.

A simple client/monitor probably is the quickest solution.

Comment: So why the down vote? Read the question, the obvious answer is that you can't do that out of box. You can do what @daniula said, but it's not serious. If something goes seriously wrong, you'll end up with 10k emails in your inbox.

Comment: That downvote is my mistake. Your solution is ok, I haven't noticed that message should be send after X fails, not every fail. I can change my vote only when your answer will be edited.